# how to avoid writing <?php in php file

Tags: php

i have one old website where my php tag start from

```
 <?
```

now i want to run on new server with php 5.x.x its not working

its working on

```
  <?php
```

can i avoid this...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to enable shorts tags:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

from php.ini

**Note:**

That would work if:

```
PHP_INI_ALL in PHP 4.0.0. PHP_INI_PERDIR in PHP < 5.3.0
```

---

**Suggestion:**

You should make it a habit of yours to always write full php tags `<?php...?>` because short tags have shown security concerns and won't be supported in the future versions.

Comment: Lol. That's a bit far-fetched. It's like calling PHP insecure by design, since your webserver might not be configured to interpret PHP code at all.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to change it to `<?php`, however, if you change `short_open_tag` in php.ini to 1 or true and reload server, it will work as well.

```
short_open_tag = 1
```

Again, it would be wiser to change all `<?` occurrences to `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure PHP to enable short open tags:

short_open_tags = 1

See the [ini file configuration docs](http://si.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Answer (score 0):

It is a configuration setting of your PHP-Installation.

short_open_tag

Answer (score 0):

Use Dreamweaver to `Replace All` instances of `<?` to `<?php` or change like the other answerers said.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid editing a centralized php.ini file and affecting all sites using the php.ini, if you're able to edit .htaccess files or apache virtualhost configs, you can add a line to the .htaccess file or virtualhost config file for a cleaner effect:

`php_value short_open_tag "1"`

Or, the more complete version for a .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    php_value short_open_tag "1"
</FilesMatch>
```